# Реализация задачи через `ADB`

Tags: java, android, android-adb

Как можно реализовать задачу через `ADB`, когда в консоли вводим команду (ну или написать скрипт какой-то не знаю как правильно объяснить) с  названием любого приложения `ADB` отправляет запрос на устройство и на устройстве начинается загрузка приложения через `play market` (будто человек зашел в маркет ввел название приложения и нажал загрузить, только все это автоматизировать) что нужно использовать для решения этой задачи?

Comment: если известна точная модель телефона то можно скриптом просто "прокликать" установку , приложения, если нет то можно делать скрин и анализировать его, нормальным решение не является, поэтому пишу в комментарии.

Comment: @pavel вы написали если известна точная модель телефона то можно скриптом просто "прокликать" установку, это как? ведь приложение нужно будет установить любое из маркета

Comment: "Как можно реализовать задачу через ADB, когда в консоли вводим команду" Сомневаюсь, что такое вообще возможно, нго знаю точно, что можно без всякого труда через ADB устанавливать программы с компьютера на устройство. Но не стоит мне верить на слово, можете почитать help в консоли и проскинуть мозгами о возможном решении проблемы, может и с нами поделитесь

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, просто установить знаю как `adb install <path_to_apk>`, но как реализовать данную задачу пока не знаю, думал может кто хоть подтолкнет на мысль какую нибудь

Comment: под словом прокликать я имел ввиду спец скрипт использующий adb shell touch x y , координаты определить экспериментально. Открыть маркет с помощью интента